# Why was Klara so insistent that Albert was innocent?

Tags: curon

In *Curon*, when Albert comes back after being arrested, Klara tells him that she always knew that he was innocent, after having insisted to her children that there was no way Albert could have killed anyone. She seems to be genuine, too.

Except, well, as we see at the beginning, she had seen him come up from the lake, after which the dead body of the other Albert floated to the surface. She knows, more or less, that he is some sort of doppelganger that killed the original Albert. Sure, they seem to like each other, but that hardly means that he is even close to harmless.

So why was she so convinced that he was innocent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for Albert2 existing is because of Anna.  The Curse of Curon is known around the town and obviously Klara had seen the results first hand.

Short and to the point:
Klara knows Albert2 exists because he wants Anna, he'd be incapable of killing her.  One of the reasons Klara split was because she had deluded herself into believing Albert2 actually loved her.  But she always knew the truth, it's why Klara accepted her death so easily, her life was a lie.